# Ошибка при установке NVIDIA Cuda 5.5 Gentoo

Tags: linux, gcc, cuda, nvidia

При установке NVIDIA Cuda 5.5 в Gentoo получаю ошибку:

> nvcc fatal: redefinition of argument 'compiler-bindir'

компилятор gcc 4.8, 4.7.3 установлен в слот, пробовал ставить основынм 4.7.3, не помогает, как фиксить?

Comment: @Флагнувший юзер, обсуждение проблем с программным обеспечением, использующимся в основном для программирования, **не являются оффтопиком** ни на SO, ни на SORU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Описание доступно в этом [багтрекере.](https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=13674)
В кратце надо немного пропатчить концовку местного makefile, чтобы убрать оттуда ключи `-ccbin` `--compiler-bindir`, которые почему-то не поддерживаются.